# Can't log struct member in truffle test

Tags: solidity, web3js, truffle, bignumber

**Contract** :

```
mapping (bytes32 => MyStruct) public myMapping;

  struct  MyStruct {
      uint256 myMember;
      uint256 someOtherMember;
  }
```

**Test (Truffle)**

This works:

```
let myStructResult = await this.contract.myMapping(id);
console.log(myStructResult);
```

But logs unfamiliar output (I'm not too solid on BN lib):

```
    Result {
  '0': '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
  '1': BN {
    negative: 0,
    words: [ 5, <1 empty item> ],
    length: 1,
    red: null
  },
  myMember: BN {
    negative: 0,
    words: [ 5, <1 empty item> ],
    length: 1,
    red: null
    },
   someOtherMember: BN {
    negative: 0,
    words: [ 5, <1 empty item> ],
    length: 1,
    red: null},
```

I see the value I want to log `myMember`, along with a few integer keys for which I don't understand their purpose

So I go:

```
let myMemberResult = await this.contract.myMapping(id).myMember;
let myMemberResultToNum = myMemberResult.toNumber()     
console.log(myMemberResult)
Result: undefined
console.log(myMemberResultToNum)
Result: cannot read property 'toNumber' of undefined
```

Why can I log the struct, but I can't log one of its members?

Comment: But 
`let myMappingResult = await this.contract.myMapping(id)

let myMemberResult = myMappingResult.myMember
console.log(myMemberResult)`
works! Trying to figure out why...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In:

```
let myMemberResult = await this.contract.myMapping(id).myMember;
```

The `this.contract.myMapping(id).myMember` part is executed before the `await` part.

You can fix it by adding parenthesis:

```
let myMemberResult = (await this.contract.myMapping(id)).myMember;
```

By the way, you could have easily concluded that from the experiment described in your own comment below the question.

As a side note, I would advise against converting `BN` to `Number`, since the latter is bound by `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` (2 ^ 53 - 1).

If you want to print it as a plain decimal number, then simply use `myMemberResult.toString()`, or better yet (in order to avoid scientific notation for extremely large values) - `myMemberResult.toFixed()`.

Comment: Actually, you fixed a major major blind spot -one which I would not have easily self corrected.  I appreciate the assistance on such a 'general' question . And thanks for the advice on big number representation